# i need to insert date into database when user clicks on login button through php

Tags: php, mysql, html

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('dbconfig/config.php');
    //phpinfo();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color:#bdc3c7">
    <div id="main-wrapper">
    <center><h2>Login Form</h2></center>
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <img src="imgs/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            </div>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">

            <div class="inner_container">
                <label><b>Username</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
                <label><b>Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
                <button class="login_button" name="login" type="submit">Login</button>
                <a href="register.php"><button type="button" class="register_btn">Register</button></a>
            </div>
        </form>

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['login']))
            {
                @$username=$_POST['username'];
                @$password=$_POST['password'];
                                @$date=$_POST[date('Y-m-d')];
                $query = "select * from userinfotbl where username='$username' and password='$password' ";
                                $query1="insert into userinfotbl values('$date')";
                //echo $query;
                $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                                $query_run1 = mysqli_query($con,query1);
                //echo mysql_num_rows($query_run);
                if($query_run)
                {
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
                    {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

                    header( "Location: homepage1.php");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("No such User exists. Invalid Credentials")</script>';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Database Error")</script>';
                }
            }
            else
            {
            }
        ?>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The date field in my database is getting filled with 0000-00-00.where i need to insert that field with the system date when the user clicks on login button.I am unable to detect the problem.I have a variable $date to which i am assigning the function date('Y-m-d').

Comment: This is just wrong: sql injection, plain-text passwords, storing passwords in the session, suppressing errors with `@`, inserting a row without any identifyable information in the database, trying to access non-existing POST variables. You should probably start over.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
@$date=$_POST[date('Y-m-d')];
```

with

```
$date=date('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Place of `@$date=$_POST[date('Y-m-d')]` use `@$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`
Select datatype DATETIME in Mysql database field.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
      @$username=$_POST['username'];
      @$password=$_POST['password'];

      //@$date=$_POST[date('Y-m-d')];
      @$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


    $query = "select * from userinfotbl where username='$username' and password='$password' ";
                    $query1="insert into userinfotbl values('$date')";
    //echo $query;
    $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                    $query_run1 = mysqli_query($con,query1);
    //echo mysql_num_rows($query_run);
    if($query_run)
    {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
        {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

        header( "Location: homepage1.php");
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("No such User exists. Invalid Credentials")</script>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Database Error")</script>';
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you only need to change the date datatype to timestamp and set default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
This will automatically add date value column and you don't need to provide date for that in query.